# Multipart body length limit exceeded exception

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Although having set the `MaxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` to the maximum possible values in the `web.config` section, ASP.Net Core does not allow me to upload files larger than `134,217,728 Bytes`. The exact error coming from the web server is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidDataException: Multipart body length limit 134217728 exceeded.

Is there any way to work this around? (**ASP.Net Core**)

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: @aguafrommars: I already solved this problem, please check my own answer.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem after reading some posts in GitHub. Conclusion is that they have to be set in the `Startup` class. For example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
        })
 }
```

This will solve the problem. However they also indicated that there is a `[RequestFormSizeLimit]` attribute, but I have been unable to reference it yet.

Comment: I don't think setting limits in web.config has any effect in an ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: Thank God I found you I was lost without you

Comment: Anyone else having problems getting this to work in the latest versions?

Comment: @JasonRowe Yes, I am. Looks like it's not working with the latest version.

Comment: @pawel, incorrect, I had to change the web.config in my azure app as well

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis: That is because it has something to do with Azure configurations! web.config is usually meant to be used by IIS, but ASP.Net Core has it's own middleware. So I think in your case, some configs also had to be done on Azure and that's why you needed to change web.config.

Comment: The OP did not mention Azure or IIS. IIS/Azure do read some settings from the web.config file. Kestrel does not.

Comment: This limit will only work for ~2GB files. Is there a different approach recommended for larger uploads?

Comment: @defect833: yes, upload your large file in small parts.

Comment: I set the second variable to the max value of long instead. My controller action has a 10gb limit for uploading the results of the client drag and dropping multiple files. 
[RequestSizeLimit(10_000_000_000)] //10gb in cheap gigs

Comment: @Tyeth Like the "cheap" gigs. Personally, I call them "peasant" gigs 

Comment: Then what's ```[DisableRequestSizeLimit]``` attribute for?!

Comment: @Babak: It is for when you target .Net Core 2.0 or higher!

Comment: The equivalent with the attribute usage :
`[HttpPost("upload"), DisableRequestSizeLimit, RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue, ValueLengthLimit = Int32.MaxValue)]`

Comment: Still getting the error ("Multipart body length limit 1000000000 exceeded"). Tried setting `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` to `long.MaxValue`, but it gets ignored for some reason.

Comment: what is the unit of `MultipartBodyLengthLimit`? is it in byte

Comment: @user3664254 use `Int32.MaxValue`

Answer (score 33):

Alternatively use the attribute, so the equivalent for an action as resolved by Transcendant would be:

```cs
[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `int.MaxValue` (2,147,483,647) for the value of `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` as suggested in other answers, you'll be allowing file uploads of approx. 2Gb, which could quickly fill up disk space on a server. I recommend instead setting a constant to limit file uploads to a more sensible value e.g. in Startup.cs

```
using MyNamespace.Constants;
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        ... other stuff
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => {
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = Files.MaxFileUploadSizeKiloBytes;
        })
 }
```

And in a separate constants class:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Constants
{
    public static class Files
    {
        public const int MaxFileUploadSizeKiloBytes = 250000000; // max length for body of any file uploaded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in case some one still face this problem i've created a middle-ware which intercept the request and create another body

```cs
    public class FileStreamUploadMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public FileStreamUploadMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Request.ContentType != null)
            {
                if (context.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key == "Content-Disposition"))
                {
                    var v = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(
                        new StringSegment(context.Request.Headers.First(x => x.Key == "Content-Disposition").Value));
                    if (HasFileContentDisposition(v))
                    {
                        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            context.Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                            var length = memoryStream.Length;
                            var formCollection = context.Request.Form =
                                new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(),
                                    new FormFileCollection()
                                        {new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, length, v.Name.Value, v.FileName.Value)});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }

        private static bool HasFileContentDisposition(ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition)
        {
            // this part of code from  https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7019#issuecomment-341626892
            return contentDisposition != null
                   && contentDisposition.DispositionType.Equals("form-data")
                   && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName.Value)
                       || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileNameStar.Value));
        }
    }
```

and in the controller we can fetch the files form the request

```cs
        [HttpPost("/api/file")]
        public IActionResult GetFile([FromServices] IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            [FromServices] IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            //save the file
            var files = Request.Form.Files;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                file.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                var fileStream = File.Create(
                    $"{environment.WebRootPath}/images/background/{file.FileName}", (int) file.Length,
                    FileOptions.None);
                fileStream.Write(memoryStream.ToArray(), 0, (int) file.Length);

                fileStream.Flush();
                fileStream.Dispose();

                memoryStream.Flush();
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

you can improve the code for your needs eg: add form parameters in the body of the request and deserialize it.

its a workaround i guess but it gets the work done.

Comment: For whom it is worth something, for IO you need async IO... Recommended.
You can use await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream) (no need for MemoryStream)