# REST .NET Core 2.2 ~ Why Get Exception "Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded."?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a **.NET Core 2.2 API** with a **POST** for a large **file upload** via **stream**.

I'm getting the **exception** **"Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded."**

The exception appears at the line...

```
section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
```

...at the FileStreamHelper.cs (see below).

I use postman to try the upload. My file has 10 MB.
I get this exception when I choose *Body/binary*.
When I choose *Body/form-data* instead I get the exception "Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.". But I did not read the file by a different component or before. **I guess binary should be right.** Right?

At my Startup.cs I define

```
        services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MemoryBufferThreshold = Int32.MaxValue;
            options.ValueCountLimit = 10; //default 1024
            options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; //not recommended value
            options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; //not recommended value
        });
```

I'm using also at the Startup.cs

```
            app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/File"),
            appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.Run(async context =>
                {
                    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = (long)( 2 * System.Math.Pow( 1024, 3 )); // = 2GB 
                    await Task.CompletedTask;
                });
            });
```

At Program.cs I use

```
            .UseKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = (long)(2 * System.Math.Pow(1024, 3)); // = 2 GB
            })
```

At my Controller I use the Attribute  *[DisableRequestSizeLimit]*.

**What could be the reason for this exception?**

**How to solve this problem?**

All code:
Controller

```
[Route("api/v1/dataPicker/fileUploadStream")]
public class FileStreamUploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
    {
        var streamer = new FileStreamingHelper();
        var paths = "c:\\temp\\";
        var tempName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        using
            (
            var stream = System.IO.File.Create($"{paths}tempName")
            )
            await streamer.StreamFile(Request, stream);
        string from = $"{paths}tempName";
        string to = $"{paths}{streamer.FileNames.FirstOrDefault() ?? tempName}";
        System.IO.File.Move(from, to);
        return Ok($"Uploaded File {paths}{streamer.FileNames.FirstOrDefault() ?? tempName}");
    }
}
```

FileStreamHelper

```
    public async Task<FormValueProvider> StreamFile(HttpRequest request, Stream targetStream)
    {
        if (!MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(request.ContentType))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Expected a multipart request, but got {request.ContentType}");
        }

        var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();

        var boundary = MultipartRequestHelper.GetBoundary(
            MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(request.ContentType),
            _defaultFormOptions.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit);
        var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);

        MultipartSection section;
        try
        {
            section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        while (section != null) ...}

    public static string GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, int lengthLimit)
    {
        var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType.Boundary);
        if (StringSegment.IsNullOrEmpty(boundary))
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException("Missing content-type boundary.");
        }

        if (boundary.Length > lengthLimit)
        {
            throw new InvalidDataException(
                $"Multipart boundary length limit {lengthLimit} exceeded.");
        }

        return boundary.Value;
    }
```

You need more code to see? Please tell me!

Here the postman Headers...
[image]

postman Body...
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @FelixToo I add the code into the initial question bottom end.

Comment: @RahulSharma It's not a duplicate because whats relevant from the linked article for Core 2.2 you find also in my code above.

Comment: From the duplicate, it mentions setting both the Kestrel limits (which you've done in code) *and* the IIS limits, which are done in Web.config, which you've not shown. Also, you use the same file name, `"tempName"` for every upload. This may cause different problems as you get more users uploading files.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My .NET Core Web Api does not have a web.config. And yes the name... Right now I would be happy to get the file streamed. I will give them unique names anywhere.

Comment: I think it is about streaming the file from **postman** to the Api, because it needs to be splitted. And I guess postman is **not splitting the file**. And the exception says that the (not splitted) binary is to big for the server or Api. Does somebody know how to define this streaming process in postman?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to retrieve the boundary this way by parsing the content type first:

```
 var contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(context.Request.ContentType);
 var boundary = HeaderUtilities.RemoveQuotes(contentType .Boundary);

 var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary.Value, request.Body);

 //Rest of the code
```

Also, please attach a screenshot of your postman request, especially the headers

Comment: The boundary I parsed to string because MultipartReader accept only string as first parameter. But it does not work. The exception is still the same.
The screen shot of postman I will add to the initial question above.

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be `boundary.Value`. I have edited my answer. How did you parse to string?

Comment: Same result. I used ToString(), but also .Value makes no difference.

Comment: Resolved the issue in a .NET 6 app. Why does this have so many upvotes?

Answer (score 1):

I had to configure postman differently..
[image]

1) Body / form-data

2) under "KEY" enter the field with your mouse, than drop down and choose "File"

3) below Value click the new Button and choose a file

4) write into the field "KEY" the word "File"

That was not easy to find out. ;-)
All the Header data wasn't important. 
Now it works.