# .Net Core API File Upload . Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Subsequent request to the file upload for .net core api fails but works for the very first request via postman.

Error : multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded.

Note : Working fine in local getting issue only in IIS

Added below code in startup.cs

> services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
> {
> options.ValueCountLimit = 10; //default 1024
> options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; //not recommended value
> options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue; //not recommended value
> });

Comment: refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968462/multipart-body-length-limit-16384-exceeded)

Comment: @XinranShen Thanks for the reply but already checked this thread, but it did not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For application running on IIS:

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

For application running on Kestrel:

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue; // if don't set 
  //default value is: 30 MB
});
```

Form's MultipartBodyLengthLimit:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // if don't set 
    //default value is: 128 MB
    options.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});
```

Adding all the above options will solve the problem related to the file upload with a size of more than 30.0 MB.

I hope its help.