# ASP.NET Core Web API : multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data, .net-core-3.1

When I built a Web API to allow the client to upload big files (more than 100 Mb), I got an error:

> Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded

I referred to links, which can be found here [linkA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968462/multipart-body-length-limit-16384-exceeded) and here [linkB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core).

Based on suggestions, I first created a simple controller with .NET Core 3.1.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestFormDataUpload.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost("upload"), DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> UploadZipperAsync([FromForm] IFormCollection uploadRequest)
        {
            return Ok(new string("upload successfully"));
        }
    }
}
```

I also configure the Kestrel server in the `Program` file, and `FormOptions` in the `Startup` file.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseKestrel(options => { options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; });
        });
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
    {
        x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.BufferBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
        x.BufferBody = true;
        x.MemoryBufferThreshold = int.MaxValue;
        x.KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
    });

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

But when I call the `upload` API in the Postman, the error is still reported.

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|c4a88f96-4f36a455f5afbcb5.",
    "errors": {
        "": [
            "Failed to read the request form. Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded."
        ]
    }
}
```

My curl command is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/api/file/upload' \
--form 'uploadedFile=@"/C:/Users/xxx/Repos/RicardoIsDebugging/netcore-trial/file-operation/ZipperClient/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/tempfile.7z"'
```

And my request headers are
[image: Postman request headers]

Can any one show me any feasibly solution? Better with code examples:)

Comment: To upload big files you should use streaming: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#upload-large-files-with-streaming

Otherwise you would risk filling your server's RAM, because the simple approach accumulates bytes in memory,